# How did the $\operatorname{div}_x$ "disappear"?

Tags: inequalities, norms

Given $E(x,t) := \nabla_x (\frac 1{|x|} * \rho)$ where $\rho : \mathbb R^3 \times [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ is defined by $\rho(x,t):=\int_{\mathbb R^3} f(x,v,t) dv$, I have understood that
$$\rho(x,t)=-\operatorname{div}_x \int_0^t s \int_{\mathbb R^3} [Ef(x-vs,v,t-s)] dv \, ds] + h(x,t),$$
where $h(x,t):=\int_{\mathbb R^3} f_0(x-vt,v) dv$. The paper I have is trying to establish for $m \ge 3$ that
$$\|E(\cdot,t)\|_{p} \le C \left\|\int_0^t s \int_{\mathbb R^3} Ef(x-vs,v,t-s) dv \, ds \right\|_{p} + \|h\|_{r} \tag{$\star$}$$
with $\frac 1p=\frac 1r-\frac 13$ and $\frac 32 < p < +\infty$.

Page 420 of the journal containining [this paper by Lions and Perthame](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN356556735_0105/PPN356556735_0105___LOG_0023.pdf) asserts this derivation.

**Edit:** [Page 12 of this PDF](http://www2.cscamm.umd.edu/~jabin/gjp7.pdf) suggests that the Calderon-Zygmund theory be used and suggests to look up the theory in [*Harmonic Analysis* by E.M. Stein](http://imcs.dvfu.ru/lib.int/docs/Math/unsorted/%C0%ED%E0%EB%E8%E7/Stein,_Harmonic_Analysis,_Real-Variable_Methods,Orthogonality,&Oscillatory_Integrals,1995.pdf). I'm not sure exactly how to apply the theory, however, especially with the $\frac 1p=\frac 1r-\frac 13$ part.

---

I understand most of how $(\star)$ was derived, but I was wondering how did the $\operatorname{div}_x$ "disappear" in deriving $(\star)$?

**Update to my thoughts:** I am aware that $E(\rho(x,t)) =E(x,t) = \nabla_x \int_{\mathbb R^3} K(x,y) \rho(y,t) \, dy$, where $K(x,y) := \frac 1{|x-y|}$ is the kernel. In this regard, I somewhat believe that $K$ is the kernel of the operator $E$.